# Adding count(*) from a join to a query

Tags: mysql, sql

Ugh...  I really struggle with these mySQL joins...

Here's what I'm after.   My current query looks like this.

```
SELECT profiles.photo, postings.postid, postings.text, postings.date, members.fname, members.lname, members.userid 
FROM profiles, postings, members
WHERE postings.wallid=postings.posterid 
AND postings.wallid=members.userid 
AND postings.wallid=profiles.userid
```

I'm trying to add in a count(*) of matching records from another table.   The other table is called `likes`, and `postings.postid = likes.post_id`.

What I've tried (and returns no results) is this...

```
SELECT profiles.photo, postings.postid, postings.text, postings.date, members.fname, members.lname, members.userid,
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM likes WHERE postings.postid=likes.post_id)
FROM profiles, postings, members, likes
WHERE postings.wallid=postings.posterid 
AND postings.wallid=members.userid 
AND postings.wallid=profiles.userid
```

What I've done here is add the nested SELECT, which I thought would resolve this.

Basically, what I'm asking...  given my first query, how can I also obtain the count of the number of records in the `likes` table where `postings.postid = likes.post_id`?   As always, any help / tips / suggestions is always appreciated.

Comment: Consider changing your joins to ANSI (i.e. with a `JOIN`/`on` keywords).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try that:

```
 SELECT profiles.photo, postings.postid, postings.text, postings.date, members.fname,members.lname, members.userid,
 likes.like_count
 FROM profiles, members, postings
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT post_id, COUNT(*) like_count FROM likes GROUP BY post_id) as likes
      ON postings.postid=likes.post_id
 WHERE postings.wallid=postings.posterid 
 AND postings.wallid=members.userid 
 AND postings.wallid=profiles.userid
```

Comment: won't you need to `group by post_id` on line 4?

Comment: Trying this now...  getting an error here...  I'll double check to make sure I'm not doing something wrong.   Error is `#1054 - Unknown column 'postings.postid' in 'on clause'`

Comment: postings.postid was in your oryginal query, that is structure of table 'postings' ?

Comment: Okay, that works great!  The other one was giving me some issue...  but this seems to be returning the result okay.

Comment: IMO better solution is, storing count of likes in 'postings' table ex. in new column 'likes_count'. Increase the value of this column, after every user comment (in transaction of couse). You do not need the grouping which is quite expensive.

Comment: @ryrysz THANKS!   That's actually a very good point...  Thinking about this as you mentioned, storing the total value would make the query much quicker.   I can use the other table to avoid duplicate 'likes' and such from the same person...  but your method would improve performance (and probably readability) quite a bit.   Thank you very much for the additional tip.

Answer (score 1):

First off, it's a lot easier to use the new-style sql syntax for this.  Conceptually, it's going to be confusing and tough to do outer joins with that old syntax.  Second, you're missing the "profile" table and mistakenly seem to have self-joined the postings table.  Try writing your queries more like this:

```
SELECT 
    profiles.photo, 
    postings.postid, 
    postings.text, 
    postings.date, 
    members.fname, 
    members.lname, 
    members.userid,
    COUNT(DISTINCT like_id) as CountOfLikes
FROM profiles
INNER JOIN postings
    ON postings.wallid=profiles.userid 
INNER JOIN members
    ON members.userid=postings.wallid
LEFT JOIN likes
    ON likes.post_id = postings.post_id;
```

Comment: Trying this now...  giving me an error...  will double check and make sure I'm copying this correctly.   Error is `#1054 - Unknown column 'like_id' in 'field list'`

Comment: I will have to take a look at this new style some more...  I've been writing queries the old way as long as I can remember, but I see where this might have some benefit when using INNER / OUTER joins... something I've always struggled with.